# How Can i use imgbb for react image hosting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

curl --location --request POST "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=600&key=YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY" --form "image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" how to use this url

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY" with an API key from imgbb. Expiration is in seconds so 600 seconds equals 10 minutes. The image can be an URL, a file or a base64 hash of file.